# Cannot read property 'nodeModulesPath' of undefined - EMBER

Tags: node.js, ember.js

After the installation of ember-power-calendar I've got this error:

> Cannot read property 'nodeModulesPath' of undefined
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeModulesPath' of undefined
>           at DependencyVersionChecker.NPMDependencyVersionChecker

I cleaned npm and bower cache, removed node_modules, bower_components, dist and tmp folders, than removed ember-power-calendar package from package json and after that run npm install && bower install.

But it didn't help.

Also I saw that ember-power-calendar has dependencies with ember-cli@2.10. But I had 2.8. I've even updated ember-cli, made steps above and it also didn't help.

The last idea is to reinstall node and npm to clean global modules. But I'm not sure that it will help.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is looking at the [following link](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases) and applying both setup and project update parts carefully if you have not done so yet.

Comment: 2 things. Please post your `package.json` file if you can. Also, if you could include a full stack trace instead of just the error that would be very helpful

Comment: I had the same problem after updating ember-bootstrap and ember-power-select. After uninstalling them (```npm uninstall ember-bootstrap --save-dev```) it was working again

Comment: I am also having this issue. Coming from line 137 of `ember-cli-version-checker`

Comment: For me removing ember-cli-font-awesome `npm uninstall ember-cli-font-awesome --save-dev` resolved it. Seems like some addons can corrupt the build.

Answer (score 2):

I've fully investigated that issue.

**Firstly, pay attention to deprecations errors in your console and try to fix them.**

After I've installed ember-power-calendar, I found in package.json of this addon that it depends on ember-cli@2.10. But I had 2.8 before that.

ember-cli@2.10 brought few deprecations (ex. this._super became mandatory in init method). That's why few addons in my app broke build.

**Update devDependencies to latest versions and I'm sure that it will help you.**

*Thank you for answers.*